# Alternative to jQuery append()

Tags: jquery

When adding text to an element, jQuery's append() function adds quotation marks around text. I want to change that, and instead separate values by comma or whatever I come up with. Is there an alternative to append() that will do that ?

To give it some context, I'm using jQuery to dynamically write to a hidden `<input>` element.

Currently after a few additions (using append) the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden">"first"
    "second"
    "third"
</input>
```

In an ideal world, the HTML ***should*** come out looking like this:

```
<input type="hidden">first, second, third</input>
```

Using jQuery to read, concatenate, and then replace the original `<input>` text might work, but I don't see a function that will do a wholesale replace of innerHTML (I'm assuing it's called that).

Thoughts ?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. INPUT elements have an empty content model - they don't have "innerHTML". It should be: `<input type="hidden" value="first, second, third">`.

Comment: Why aren't you setting the input element's value?

Comment: Good call, I didn't even realize they were inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem here is that `input` values are set in the `value` attribute, not as an inner child:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myInput" name="myInput" value="first">
```

To do what you seem to want, you'd probably want to change the value of the input with `.val()`:

```
$('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val() + ', second');
```

Answer (score 3):

in jquery:

```
<div id="test"></div>

$('#test').append('a');
$('#test').append('b');

will look like this (in chrome dev tool):
<div id="test">
"a"
"b"
</div>
```

while

```
<div id="test"></div>

$('#test').html($('#test').html() + 'a');
$('#test').html($('#test').html() + 'b');

will look like this:

<div id="test">ab</div>
```

the dom tree in both cases is the same, only it shows it in chrome dev tool with the quotes (they are not really there, right click -> edit as html and they will disappear)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could append text to a hidden span:

```
<style> #hidden { display:none; } </style>

<span id="hidden"></span>

<script>
var x; // Where 'x' is the data that you would like to append.
$('#hidden').append(x);
</script>
```

Comment: Won't be submitted with the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.iappend = function(str) {
        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val().length > 0) {
                $this.val($this.val() + "," + str);
            } else {
                $this.val($this.val() + str);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I haven't fully tested it yet.. but it ***should*** work..

```
$("#hidden").iappend("first").iappend("second").iappend("third");
```

output

> Hello,World,!